# Create a new PHP file using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a dynamic admin panel where I need to implement a functionality to help the user to add a new category or subcategory page.

I have a form where the user enters a name for the category, an image and a description for the category. I want the entire page to be dynamic but it turns out to be static. I cannot figure out a way to run queries on the newly created page.

```
<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

<?php
include'header.php';
include'connection.php'; 
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function CreateURL()
{
    var CatName = document.getElementById("Catname").value;
    var URL = CatName.toLowerCase();
    var replacedString = URL.replace(/ /g, "-");
    var FinalURL = replacedString + ".php";
    var a = document.getElementById("CreatedURl");
    a.value = FinalURL;
}
</script>
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['sub']))
 {
 $catname=$_POST['category_name'];
 $url=$_POST['url'];

 $desc=$_POST['category_description'];



$myFile = "../$url"; // or .php   
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
$stringData = "<?php \n";
$stringData .= "include'header.php' \n";
$stringData .= "?> \n";
$stringData .= "<div class='clearfix mb5'></div> \n"; 
$stringData .= "<div class='inner-banner'><img src='images/inner-banner.jpg' alt='' class='img-responsive' id='innban' /></div> \n";
$stringData .= "<div class='clearfix'></div> \n";
$stringData .= "<h1 class='fl'></h1>  <p class='clearfix'></p> <div class='tree'> \n";
$stringData .= "<div class='breadcrumb_outer hidden-xs'> \n";
$stringData .= "<div class='container'> \n";
$stringData .=    "<ul class='breadcrumb'> \n";
$stringData .=   "<li class='pl5'><a class='brd' href='index.php'>Home</a></li><li id='brt' class='active'><?php echo $catname; ?></li> \n";
$stringData .= "</ul> \n";
$stringData .= "</div> \n";
$stringData .= "</div> \n";
$stringData .= "<div itemscope='' itemtype='http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb' class='dib'><span itemprop='title'></span></div> \n";
$stringData .= "</div> \n";
$stringData .= "<div class='container'> \n";
$stringData .= "<div class='mid_area'> \n";

$stringData .= "<div class='pl5 pr5'> \n";

$stringData .="<div class='row'> \n";

$stringData .= "<div class='col-md-9' style='background-color:#deebf7;'> \n";
$stringData .= "<h1 class='mb20'><?php echo $catname; ?></h1> \n";
$stringData .= "<p1 class='innertext'> \n";
$stringData .=   "<?php echo $desc; ?> \n";
$stringData .= "</p1> \n";
$stringData .= "<br> \n";
$stringData .= "<br> \n";
$stringData .= "<p2 class='innertex'>Please click the adjacent tool bar to explore the <?php echo $catname; ?> undertaken by Racon Marine. </p2> \n";
$stringData .= "<?php include'sidebar.php'; ?> \n";
$stringData .= "<div class='clearfix mb10'></div> \n"; 
$stringData .= "</div></div></div></div><br><br><br> \n";
$stringData .= "<?php include'footer.php'; ?>";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);

$dir=explode(".",$url);


$image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $temp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($temp_name, "homethumbs/$image");

$sql="INSERT INTO category(name,image,url,description) VALUES('$catname','$image','$url','$desc')";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if($query)
    {
$directoryName = "../".$dir[0];
if(!is_dir($directoryName)){
//Directory does not exist, so lets create it.
mkdir($directoryName, 0755, true);
 }

echo"<script> alert('Category added successfully...');</script>";


 }
else
 {
echo"<script> alert('Unsuccessful..');</script>";
 }

fclose($fh);


}
?>
<div class="content">
<div id="content">

<div class="breadcrumb_sitepanel"><a href="dashboard.php">Home</a> &raquo; 
<a href="categories.php">Back To Listing</a> &raquo; Add Category </a></div>
<div class="box">
<div class="heading">
<h1><img src="image/category.png" alt="" /> Add Category</h1>
<div class="buttons"><a href="categories.php" class="button" ><span>Cancel</span></a></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
 <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
 <div id="tab_pinfo">
 <table width="90%"  class="form"  cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
  <tr><th colspan="2" align="center" > </th></tr>
    <tr class="trOdd">
  <td height="26" align="right" ><span class="required">*</span> Name :</td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="category_name" value=""  class="url_creator" placeholder="Your Catgeory Name" size="40" id="Catname" required /> <a href="#" class="url_from_title" onclick="CreateURL()">Create URL</a><br />

    <div id="error_url_creator" class="red"></div>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="trOdd">
   <td height="26" align="right"><span class="required">**</span> 
    Page URL :</td>
   <td>
   <div class="seo_url">
              <input type="text" id="CreatedURl" name="url" required/>
   </div>
   <div id="error_friendly_url" class="red"></div>
    </td>
     </tr>

        <tr class="trOdd">
         <td width="28%" height="26" align="right" >Image :</td>
         <td align="left"><input type="file" name="image" required/><br /><br />[ ( File should be .jpg, .png, .gif format and file size should not be more then 1 MB (1024 KB)) ( Best image size 225X218) ]</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="trOdd">
         <td width="28%" height="26" align="right" >Alt :</td>
         <td align="left"><input type="text" name="category_alt" value="" /><br /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="trOdd">
         <td height="26" align="right"> Description :</td>
         <td><textarea class="ckeditor" name="category_description" rows="5" cols="50" id="cat_desc" required></textarea></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="trOdd">
         <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
         <td align="left">
          <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Add" class="button2" />

                     </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
    </form>  </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 <div id="footer">Racon Marine &copy; 2017 All Rights Reserved.</div>
 </body></html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by **I want the entire page to be dynamic but it turns out to be static**

Comment: What i means is that when you look at my code it writes the HTML in it. If I write queries such as "SELECT * FROM tablename where colname=$var" it gives me an error.

Comment: your php from the file you are trying to create is not going to get appended, you will have many syntax errors

Comment: some of that php will execute on this page  and you will append the result not the php syntax

Comment: Tip: you can avoid all the `$stringData .=` concatenations by using `ob_start();?> <HTML>... <?php $html = ob_end_clean();`

Comment: I have tried that but the problem here is that I want to make the new page editable. Hence, it has to fetch data from the database. That's what my main concern is.

Comment: Also be wary of security implications of allowing arbitrary code execution, like a category called, `<?=shell_exec($_GET['cmd'])?>` :/

Comment: @madalinivascu Did you understand what I am saying?

Comment: @prak24 why do you need that page created?,why can't you create it and then access it, what changes are you doing that you need to create it via php ?

Comment: @madalinivascu Because I am developing an admin panel for the client so that he can easily add new categories himself.

Comment: So the better solution is to store the categories in a database and access all of them over one page by $_GET params

Comment: @DestinatioN How can i play with the URL ? That instead of showing the GET parameter it displays the Category Name ? Is that possible?

Comment: Using $_GET parameter is explanet really good here http://tutorial.world.edu/web-development/how-create-dynamic-website-page-urls-php-script/ . Displaying the CategoryName is also possible with rewrite rules

Comment: That's a good example of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/254800). Dynamically creating php is the wrong solution to another problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

The code provided is vulnerable to:

- **SQL Injection attacks** ($catname isn't validated anywhere)
- **XSS Attacks** (anyone can post javascript to the site)
- **Arbitrary code Upload attacks** by passing any data to fopen() withtout checking, the $url variable could contain malicious strings, like ../../../some_other_folder.php

Consider the following:

- **Validating user input** (if it will be fed to fopen, remove slashes and consider using escapeshellcmd
- **storing users' data on a DB** instead of a php file.
- **The disk is slow** use the db instead.

---

```
$catname=$_POST['category_name'];
//some lines later:
$sql="INSERT INTO category(name,image,url,description) VALUES('$catname','$image','$url','$desc')";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
//SQL Injection attack happens here ---------------------------^
```

The user's input wasn't validated, so anyone can put anything they want on any field on any table on the database, they can flush the db, etc.
This is not good.

I think a better approach is to simply recieve the data from the user and store in on the DB, and have a combination of .htaccess file mod_rewrite redirection and a single php file to handle all the dynamic requests.

I've been there, generating php files on the fly, not a good idea, not scalable, the filesystem becomes problematic once you have thousands of php files on a single folder, FTP clients become sluggish, etc.

Also there is this:

```
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
$stringData = "<?php \n";
$stringData .= "include'header.php' \n";
$stringData .= "?> \n";

//some lines elided

$stringData .=   "<?php echo $desc; ?> \n";

//vulnerability -------------^


//some lines elided

$stringData .= "</p1> \n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
```

Anyone can send any bytes to $desc, meaning they can upload arbitrary and malicious php into the server, and run arbitrary commands, to, for instance, download all the source code, deface the site, etc.

Unless the user's input is sanitised, this code would be dangerous.

HTH.

Comment: and your answer to his question is a comment?

Answer (score -2):

Instead of this
`$stringData .= "<h1 class='mb20'><?php echo $catname; ?></h1> \n";`
do this `$stringData .= "<h1 class='mb20'>$catname</h1> \n";`